# No space inside the house, where do you store / secure bike?

Tags: storage

I live in the UK. At my house, I don't have much space, I have a drive-way but no gate surrounding it. Here's an image:

[image: home]

What are my cheap storage options for a mountain bike (voodoo bizango).

Thanks

Comment: No backyard, no cellar, no attic, nothing? Clearly, if you can/will not store it inside the house, you will be forced to store it outside.

Comment: No attic, no cellar, no back garden access from the front of the house. Are there like bike storage solutions? Like a cage or something :/

Comment: There are some great secure bike storage options, however most of them don't really qualify as cheap.
http://www.asgardsss.co.uk/bike-cycle-storage

For a cheaper option, some diy stores do some multi purpose lockers that could be used for a bike, wheelie bins, lawn mower etc.

Comment: Make a shed from the pallets, train the cat to guard it :-)

Comment: To expand on @J86's comment for those overseas: cellars are rare in the UK and tend to have rather small access hatches when they do exist. SImilarly our loft hatches tend to be too small to take a whole bike - I *might* get mine through with the wheels off but not with them on, and I've fitted a bigger hatch than originally present.

Comment: No chance to take the bike through the house into the back garden? How often do you ride it (if daily, significant dismantling isn't an option, for example).  There are [solutions, but they're expensive and rather large](https://www.diy.com/departments/protect-a-cycle-pent-metal-bike-store-6x3/260274_BQ.prd) - you could actually get a knackered old van for the same money and keep that on the drive as a shed.

Comment: An urban apartment strategy is to [hang it on the wall.](https://www.google.com/search?q=wall+hanging+bicycle&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)

Comment: There are a number of inside bike storage options, mostly involving "hangers" of various types.

Comment: "out of sight" of the road/miscreants is always a good idea.

Comment: I see a garage.  Is that available to you?

Comment: A friend of mine uses Cycloc (https://cycloc.com/ps/) to store his bike inside.

Comment: @JimmyJames that looks like next door's garage, and the door next to the no. 48  wheely bins looks like part of an extension where the garage would have been. (Assuming typical British semi-detached housing layouts)

Comment: Another question for you (@J86): how much can you do to the house? e.g. if you're renting, fixing big anchors for locks might be an issue - or you may be allowed to do it at your own cost and then leave expensive hardware when you move.

Comment: Whatever solution you choose in the outside, consider adding an automatic light directed to the bike. Thieves don't like to be enlightened, so shinning a big bright light on them usually scares them away.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov An attic really isn't a suitable place to store a bike that gets used with any frequency.

Comment: @ChrisH I own the house, so fixing anchors is OK.

Comment: I kept mine on the stairwell landing of a small London flat. Once you pop the front wheel off, the bike can lay very flat against a wall.

Answer (score 7):

You can get wooden storage sheds for bicycles for around £150 - £200.

[image: shed]

You'll also need something to secure the bike to. You could install a ground anchor, either the screw in type:

[image: ground anchor]

Or the type that you embed in concrete:

[image: ground anchor]

Comment: That tyre really should be inflated or the bike hanged above ground.

Comment: @VladimirF seems to me that the tyre is fine; the shed's door frame covers it, giving it the illusion of being flat.

Comment: I don't understand the type of anchor that is simply screwed into the ground - what would prevent a thief from simply unscrewing it and taking it with the bike?

Comment: @anderas many of those fixings are designed to be hard to remove, if not impossible.  In that design the ball bearings presumably go into the screw head after fitting.  In others the screw head snaps off leaving a cone with nothing to grip.  In most cases a decent bike lock will also make access to the screw heads hard - I'd use a motorbike chain with that red fitting. If used with the shed as pictured, you could carry off the paving slab it was screwed to - it needs more than that

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks for the explanation! I wondered what the BBs were for. Now it makes complete sense to me.

Comment: @ChrisH how may the anchors be removed (legitimately)?

Comment: @gschenk with an angle grinder. Noisy, possibly messy, but quite quick. Several approaches depending on speed vs tidiness

Answer (score 6):

Storing a bike outside leaves you with two problems to deal with: thieves and weather. No perfect solution for either problem exists unless you build something around your bike that starts qualifying as storing it "inside".

Against theft, use the biggest chains and U-locks that you can find to bound your wheels and saddle, use anti-theft QR skewers for axles. Lock the frame to the burliest stationary object you can find around. I do not see any reasonable candidates on your picture though. You might just want to install your own bike rack by screwing it down to the pavement with huge bolts.

Against the weather, provide some protection against the rain by covering the bike with a tarp. You cannot protect it against low temperatures outside, but direct water contact is by far the worst. Make sure the tarp is well fastened to not be blown away by a strong gust of wind.

A cage would be good enough only if it is made of steel bars 10 mm or more in diameter (otherwise it would be easier to cut it than a lock on its door). I can imagine that one big enough to fit in a bike (2 meter × 1 meter × 1,5 meter) would cost more than a decent bike rack. On a plus side, it might possibly be so heavy that it would not require bolting it down to the pavement. And then you can make a roof for it and it will become storing a bike inside.

You might still want to consider finding a place to store an expensive bike inside, like renting a storage room or an underground parking spot somewhere nearby. Or just suck it and bring it inside your home and hang it from the ceiling or disassemble it before storing.

Comment: Regarding the "just bring it inside" option: Loosening the stem and turning the handlebars is relatively trivial and drastically reduces the storage footprint of a bike.

Answer (score 5):

Since you’re from the UK, I’d be remiss if I didn’t suggest you get the greatest folding bike ever invented, the Brompton:

[image: brompton]

But if you already bought a bike, you might want to look into storing it in your house either horizontally:

[image: horizontal bike stand]

Or vertically. The vertical stands in particular take up little room:

[image: verical bike stand]

Finally, as @Daniel Hicks notes, it's also possible to buy and mount a pulley system that will let you lift the bike to the ceiling, either horizontally or vertically.

Comment: There are also schemes for suspending the bike from the ceiling.